# video taken by kinect camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to acess a video taken by a kinect camera using matlab

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47380/video-taken-by-kinect-camera/) by [surumi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3521/surumi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-04**:
Are you using ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that you're intending to do some sort of processing on the frames from the video stream...

If you use the [imread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) method and the [mjpeg_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mjpeg_server) it should still be possible to use something like `img=imread('http://localhost:8080/snapshot?topic=/IMAGE_TOPIC')` to access the current image.

I hope speed isn't a concern for your application, it's been a while since I tried something like this, and if memory serves me well, it took about 1-2 seconds per frame for the images that I was sending.

(As a note, I do not remember if there was any magic associated with telling matlab the file extension since it's not included in the url)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0